# How can i compute spatial statistics in grid space of two NetCDF files?

Tags: geospatial, netcdf, python-xarray, cdo-climate

I have two files with the same spatial and temporal dimension, with ERA5_w1 being the observation and CCMP_w1 being the forecast file.

I wonder how I can calculate the  R-M-S-E to get a spatial distribution of the  R-M-S-E over the 28 timesteps in a 3-dimensional field?

File information and download link are below:

[image: ERA5_w1]

[image: CCMP_w1]

I would like to generate an R-M-S-E plot like the image below:

[image]

Link to download the files: [Files](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvO08oBWX0Vtg9dmKiPKgzR3FfeV4A?e=Eq2Efc)

Comment: you can certainly do this in xarray too - implementing RMSE is pretty trivial. Can you post what you've tried and where you're stuck? also, [please don't upload images of data, code, or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, paste them as [formatted code blocks](/help/formatting). For datasets, you can paste the output generated by `print(ds)`, or better yet, create the data synthetically to form a [mre]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option for doing this is my package nctoolkit. The following code will calculate RSME for your data.

```
import nctoolkit as nc
# load the two files as datasets
ds1 = nc.open_data("CCMP_w1")
ds2 = nc.open_data("ERA5_w1")
# subtract the data in one dataset from the other
ds1.subtract(ds2)
#square the differences
ds1.power(2)
# sum up over all time steps
ds1.tsum()
# divide by the number of time steps
ds1.divide(28)
#square the results
ds1.sqrt()
# view the results
ds1.plot("WS10")
```

At present there isn't an explicit `rsme` method in nctoolkit, but I plan to add one in an upcoming release.

More details about the package [here](https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend! Do you have any documentation on how I could do the same to get MAE, MAPE and other metrics? 

I appreciate it!

Comment: You could calculate all of those using a similar approach to that above with the arithmetic methods listed here https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html